# POST request and Node.js without Nerve

Tags: post, node.js

Is there any way to accept POST type requests without using Nerve lib in Node.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the **http.Server** class of Node.js accepts [any http method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).
You can get the method using `request.method` ([api link](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/http.html#request.method)).

Example:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
   http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write(request.method);
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);

sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

This will create a simple http server on the port 8000 that will echo the method used in the request.

If you want to get a *POST* you should just check the `request.method` for the string "POST".

---

Update regarding `response.end`:

Since version 0.1.90, the function to close the response is `response.end` instead of `response.close`. Besides the name change, `end` can also send data and close the response after this data is sent unlike close. ([api example](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/synopsis.html#synopsis))

Comment: Thanks Maushu. One correction, it is "response.close();" instead "response.end();"...

Comment: From 0.1.90 it's `response.end()`, IIRC